# Clearing the Session failure: Django Form to pickled ML prediction

Tags: python, django, keras

I currently have a pickled model for predicting survivability of Titanic based on user inputs of a Django form. After a few days at this, I am now able to finally get a response to the front end of whether someone survived!

After submission, i use django.contrib message to send a "survived" or "perished" underneath the form. However, after the first submission, the fields clear in the form, but when i try to enter in new values and submit, i get a '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value' error. 
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrxhE.png), [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPEw2.png)

Now, if i restart the django server and refresh the page, i can run the POST again, but just not consecutivetly on the same session. so i dug around and someone had a statement included in a similar project where they "from kera import backend as K" and then added below right before the return in the function:

```
K.clear_session()
```

But when i put that into my code, I get the same Attribute Error as before but i get it on the first form submission, rendering it copletely useless.

So, how can I use the form to repeatedly query the model with each use being independent. the outcome of the project would be to put online to have people be able to also fill out the form so more than 1 use at a time is critical.

my code for the 'views.py': https://github.com/CourseCharter/MLshowcase/blob/master/titanic/views.py

snippet:

```
def survived(unit):
try:
    mdl=jload("/Users/user/projects/mlshowcase/titanic/titanic_model.pkl")
    #mydata=pd.read_excel('/Users/sahityasehgal/Documents/Coding/bankloan/test.xlsx')
    sc=StandardScaler()
    X=sc.fit_transform(unit)
    y_pred=mdl.predict_classes(X)
    #newdf=pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=['Survived'])
    #newdf=newdf.replace({1:'Survived', 0:'Perished'})
    return (str(y_pred))    
except ValueError as e:
    return Response(e.args[0], status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def titanic_page_guess(request):

if request.method =='POST':
    form=TitanicForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sex=form.cleaned_data['sex']
        pclass=form.cleaned_data['pclass']
        age=form.cleaned_data['age']
        relatives=form.cleaned_data['relatives']
        fare=form.cleaned_data['fare']
        myDict = (request.POST).dict()
        df=pd.DataFrame(myDict, index=[0])
        df=df.drop(['csrfmiddlewaretoken'], axis=1)
        answer = survived(df)[0]
        messages.success(request, 'Your Fate: {}'.format(answer))


form=TitanicForm()

return render(request, 'titanic/testform.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a better solution, which was to add a results page and reset the form as new during the function.

```
def result(request):
        if request.method =='POST':
            form=TitanicForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                sex=request.POST.get('sex')
                pclass=request.POST.get('pclass')
                age=request.POST.get('age')
                relatives=request.POST.get('relatives')
                fare=request.POST.get('fare')

                context = {
                    'sex': sex,
                    'pclass': pclass,
                    'age': age,
                    'relatives': relatives,
                    'fare': fare,
                }
                #create Dataframe
                df=pd.DataFrame(context, index=[0])
                #send df to model
                mdl=load("titanic/titanic_model.pkl")
                sc=load("scalars.pkl")
                df=sc.transform(df)
                y_pred=mdl.predict_classes(df)
                y_pred=pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=['Survived'])
                y_pred=y_pred.replace({1:'Lived', 0:'Perished'})
                form=TitanicForm()

            return render(request, 'titanic/result.html', {'pred': y_pred.iloc[0]['Survived']})

        else:
            form=TitanicForm()

        return render(request, 'titanic/titanic_home.html', {'form': form})
```